# "Missing Authentication Token" Error when calling DVLA MOT history API with Postman

Tags: rest, api, post, postman

Note - I am very much new to all this.  Apologies if anything is unclear.

My overriding aim is to pull out MOT history data for a large batch of vehicles from the DVLA API.  I understand that this can be done using Postman, which I am using (on a 64-bit Windows laptop if at all relevant).

The DVLA provide the following instructions

====================================================

**Getting started**

All API interfaces are implemented as restful APIs and accessed over https.

To access API you will need an API key that uniquely identifies the source of the request. DVSA will give you an API key if it approves your application.

You should keep your API key secure, as DVSA manages throttling and quotas at an API key level.

Each request must have the following mandatory fields in the header:

Accept: application/json+v6
x-api-key: 
Content-type field confirms that the response type is in JSON format, and the x-api-key field serves your API key to identify the source of the request.

**Technical resources**

Access the API at https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/

This root URL will change when the service moves from beta to live.

These 4 endpoints equate to the 4 methods of using the API:

/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?registration={registration}

‘Registration’ is the vehicle registration number.

===================================================

In order to test that this is possible, I am entering the following single request into the bar in Postman, selecting "POST" and hitting "SEND"

https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?Content-type=application/json&x-api-key=ABCDEFGH&registration=MYREG

n.b. no inverted commas or other punctuation surrounds the actual values for ABCDEFH or MYREG

**Expected result**: Some sort of JSON with MOT history for this vehicle

**Actual result**: {"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}

I am unclear on:
- whether I should be using POST

- what the +v6 after the application is necessary (other documentation leaves it out)
- Why "Accept" and "Content-type" appear to be used interchangeably in the documentation
- Whether the ordering of the parameters matters
- Whether this can be equally tested by simply pasting the url into a browser

Thanks for any help

Comment: You would need to add those as Headers rather that query params like you have done in the URL. The registration is probably the only query param - not seen the API docs so don't know for sure

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the Documentation found here:

https://dvsa.github.io/mot-history-api-documentation/

It mentions that those fields should be added as `Headers`:

```
Each request must have the following mandatory fields in 
the header:

- Accept: application/json+v6
- x-api-key: <your api key>
```

There are example `cURL` requests on the site to help you with creating the request.

If you use Postman's `Import` feature within the app (found in the top right), you can add this cURL request in the `Paste Raw Text` tab.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v6" -H "x-api-key: <your_api_key>" https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=ZZ99ABC
```

[image: Postman]

This will give you an example request of what it should look like. From here, you will be able to add in your own API Token and send the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postman, you can use the `Authorization` tab right under the request to give the required mandatory header fields.  Select `Header` from `Add to` drop down. You can also add additional headers information using the next tab named `Headers`. (for example, the accept-headers).

**Edit:**
Authorization:
[image]

Headers Tab
[image]
<s>Normally, you should be getting the authorization token when you register to the site in question(x-api-key here).You need to figure out the value of that token from the initial call's response headers.</s> According to the document which Danny shared, you will be getting x-api-key from them once they approve your request.

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you can use import feature as Danny suggested in his answer. At the end of the day, you need to add the values as headers instead of query parameters.

Comment: This wouldn't really work in this context, given they method they have to get the API token.

Comment: I believe you and I were referring to the same thing, Danny. At the end of the day, both the answers point to adding headers  (x-api-key and accept) to the request. Difference is that you used import feature of Postman while I was suggesting of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Python with the MOT history api and getting the same error message, try GET:

```
import requests

url = f'https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?registration={plate_number}'

payload = {}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json+v6',
    'x-api-key': 'your-api-key'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

data = response.json()
model = data[0]['model']  # get the vehicle model for example
print(model)
```